# Can I have a field in Salesforce that decides what to select based on a figure entered manually into FormAssembly?

Tags: formula-field, fields

I collect financial information from people applying to a programme using FormAssembly. I then use connectors to transfer this information into a related field in Salesforce.

The applicant enters the turnover of their business by typing the figure into the FormAssembly form, so it is usually a very precise amount ie. £257,688. This is relevant, and we need that specific amount. However I would also like this figure to be connected to a second field in Salesforce, where rather than seeing the specific amount, I can see which 'band' that figure sits in, so it would be a picklist with several 'bands' ie. £0 - £84,999; £85,000 - £249,999; £250,000 - £499,999 etc. My example would sit in the third band of those I just listed.

Is this possible, and if so how?

Answer: I executed the fix in FormAssembly rather than Salesforce, and the code was: @IF(%%tfa_2177%%>=14999999,"£15M - £24.99M”,@IF(%%tfa_2177%%>=9999999,"£10M - £14.99M",@IF(%%tfa_2177%%>=4999999,"£5M - £9.99M",@IF(%%tfa_2177%%>=1999999,"£2M - £4.99M",@IF(%%tfa_2177%%>=999999,"£1M - £1.99M",@IF(%%tfa_2177%%>=499999,"£500,000 - £999,999",@IF(%%tfa_2177%%>=249999,"£250,000 - £499,999",@IF(%%tfa_2177%%>=84999,"£85,000 - £249,999"))))))))

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Formula field image BETWEEN numbers](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/120710/formula-field-image-between-numbers) instead of showing an image, you can display the `band` value you need.

Comment: McCubo, thank you, this does look like it might help! Really appreciate your response.